# Cascades layout issue - can't scroll a ListView in a DockLayout

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm trying to display an `ActivityIndicator` while my list data is loading. Here's my Page QML:

```
Page {
    signal articleClicked(variant article)

    id: root

    titleBar: TitleBar {
        title: qsTr("All feeds")
        visibility: ChromeVisibility.Visible
    } // titleBar

    Container {
        layout: DockLayout {}
        ListView {
            dataModel: _feedModel
            listItemComponents: [
                ListItemComponent {
                    type: "item"

                    FeedListComponent {
                        feed: ListItemData
                    }
                }
            ]
            visible: !_manager.working

            onTriggered: {
                if (indexPath.length > 1) {
                    root.articleClicked(dataModel.data(indexPath));
                }
            }
        } // ListView

        ActivityIndicator {
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            running: _manager.working
        }
    } // Root container
} // Page
```

To display the `ActivityIndicator` centered, I'm using a `DockLayout`. It's working fine. However, when I switch `_manager.working` to `false` and display the `ListView`, I can't scroll. I guess it's not limited to the screen size, so it thinks that it's not needed to scroll, as all items are visible. But they're not. I tried to add `verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill` and `horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill` to the `ListView`, without any change. Any hint on how can I force the `ListView` to fit on screen? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that your listview won't scroll, it's that the ActivityIndicator is on top of the listview preventing the touch events from propagating down to the listview beneath it.  Try adding

visible: _manager.working

to the ActivityIndicator

Now your touch events will pass through to the listview when the listview is visible.